# R data.table Setting the remainder of column values to next column value if exceeding a certain threshold for a large data set

Tags: r, optimization, data.table, threshold

I am working on an simple peak shaving algorithm and looking for the most optimized way of setting the remainder of column values to the next column if the value exceeds a certain threshold for a large time series.

Considering I have the following example dataset with certain threshold set for each threshold, the goal is to get a data.table where the values are capped off by their threshold and the remainder are added to the next column value (not exceeding their threshold) and so on to a certain window limit.

```
loads <- data.table(index = 1:3,
                    time1 = c(6600,3000, 12000),
                    time2 = c(12000, 4000, 2000),
                    time3 = c(0, 0, 0),
                    time4 = c(3000,12000,0),
                    time5 = c(5000, 2000, 3000),
                    time6 = c(0, 0, 0),
                    time7 = c(15000, 0, 0))

thresholds <- c("time1" = 5000, 
                "time2" = 5000,
                "time3" = 5000,
                "time4" = 12000,
                "time5" = 12000,
                "time6" = 12000,
                "time7" = 5000)
```

With a window of 7 columns this should result in the following data.table:

```
res <- data.table(index = 1:3,
                  time1 = c(5000, 3000, 5000),
                  time2 = c(5000, 4000, 5000),
                  time3 = c(5000, 0, 4000),
                  time4 = c(6600, 12000, 0),
                  time5 = c(5000, 2000, 3000),
                  time6 = c(0, 0, 0),
                  time7 = c(5000, 0, 0))
```

I know there are some obvious ways to do this row-wise, but I am looking for a more vectorized/data.table approach to do this.

Comment: I think you have to go for a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is easy (or even possible?) with "just" vectorized/`data.table`-canonical code, but here's a straight-forward `for` loop that does it as `data.table`-efficiently (I think) as reasonable.

Up front: I add `timeX` to both `thresholds` (`Inf` limit) and `loads` (value of `0`) as a catch-all column so we know how much from the remainders of the row has been "lost". It's handy to have it for the `for` loop, as well (though can be done without, with some code-rewrite).

```r
library(data.table)
thresholds <- c("time1" = 5000, 
                "time2" = 5000,
                "time3" = 5000,
                "time4" = 12000,
                "time5" = 12000,
                "time6" = 12000,
                "time7" = 5000,
                "timeX" = Inf)
loads[, timeX := 0 ]

for (ind in seq_along(thresholds)) {
  if (ind >= length(thresholds)) break
  nm <- names(thresholds)[ind]
  nm1 <- names(thresholds)[ind+1]
  rmndr <- pmax(0, loads[[nm]] - thresholds[ind])
  set(loads, i = NULL, j = nm, value = pmin(loads[[nm]], thresholds[ind]))
  set(loads, i = NULL, j = nm1, value = loads[[nm1]] + rmndr)
}
loads
#    index time1 time2 time3 time4 time5 time6 time7 timeX
#    <int> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     1  5000  5000  5000  6600  5000     0  5000 10000
# 2:     2  3000  4000     0 12000  2000     0     0     0
# 3:     3  5000  5000  4000     0  3000     0     0     0
```

Or if you really don't care about the discarded numbers, then

```r
## using unmodified `loads` and `thresholds`
for (ind in seq_along(thresholds)) {
  nm <- names(thresholds)[ind]
  rmndr <- pmax(0, loads[[nm]] - thresholds[nm])
  set(loads, i = NULL, j = nm, value = pmin(loads[[nm]], thresholds[nm]))
  if (ind == length(thresholds)) break
  nm1 <- names(thresholds)[ind+1]
  set(loads, i = NULL, j = nm1, value = loads[[nm1]] + rmndr)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this already helps a lot,  already tried something similar, but this seems faster!

Although not really clear from the example I am also considering to slice the calculation up across columns (so for 1:7, 8:14 and so on..) and was wondering whether to apply the function (without the discarded numbers) vectorized on the slices. 

Already thought that vectorizing it might be difficult, but it seemed so trivial doing it in a spreadsheet :-)!

Comment: The order or spacing of columns doesn't matter, as long as `threshold` has them in the correct order. If you have multiple bands of columns that should be cascaded independently of the other bands, then you'll need another `for` loop, but that's fairly simple (e.g., `for (thresholds in list(thresh1, thresh2, thresh3)) { ... }` should do it).